# Generating function for the number of vertices of symmetric configuration complexes

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, generating-functions, combinatorial-proofs

Let a ($D_4$-)**symmetric configuration-$\Gamma$ complex** be a planar graph with the [symmetry group of the square](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Symmetry_Group_of_Square), i.e. the octic group $D_4$, in which the vertices with maximal degree have the same [vertex configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_configuration) $\Gamma$. For the sake of simplicity, assume that $\Gamma$ has the form $(3.n)^m$ with $n>3$ and $m>2$.

#### Example: $(3.4)^3$

[image]

These are the most simple examples $\mathcal{C}_2$, $\mathcal{C}_3$ which are symmetric $(3.4)^3$ complexes:

#### $\mathcal{C}_2$

[image]

#### $\mathcal{C}_3$

[image]

*[Side question: For which vertex configurations $\Gamma$ do $D_4$-symmetric $\Gamma$ complexes exist?]*

Let $|\mathcal{C}_n|$ be the number of vertices of $\mathcal{C}_n$. We count $|\mathcal{C}_2| = 36$ and
$|\mathcal{C}_3| = |\mathcal{C}_2| + 4 \cdot 26 = 140$ .

In general we have $|\mathcal{C}_{n+1}| = |\mathcal{C}_n| + 4 \cdot f(n)$ with $f(2) = 7$ and $f(3) = 26$ for $\Gamma = (3.4)^3$, where $\mathcal{C}_1$ is this graph (not a symmetric configuration complex):

[image]

> What I am looking for is a generating function for either
> $|\mathcal{C}_n|$ or $f(n)$, either for the specific vertex
> configuration $(3.4)^3$, or general $(3.n)^m$, or even for arbitrary
> vertex configurations.

Comment: I don't understand what is $C_n$. Are you picking the vertices of $C_{n-1}$, and turning the outward vertices to be $(3.4) ^3$?